# Issue with returning react component from function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to return a list of myCustomComponent from a list so they it can be rendered but it throws this error or goes into the infinity loop. The error is as follows:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression react

```
const renderMyData = () => {
  // groupedData is an array in the component made through useState()
  const myData = groupedData.map((c, index) => {
    return <MyCustomComponent key={index} data={c} />; It goes into the infinity loop
  });
  return myData;
};
```

Function is called like this in the component:

{renderMyData()}

Comment: Please provide some additional code, like how are you calling this function.